# ng-grid Cell Row/Column Index

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid, and I am trying to implement pasting into it from Excel.  In order to do so I need to know what the index (row, column) of the currently selected cell is.  Does anyone know where this info is?  I have been able to get the row index from the data passed to the beforeSelectionChange event, however that data doesn't seem to have a column index on it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This also appears in the ng-grid issues tracker, in case someone has a similar issue and is looking for pointers: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching over to the ui-grid update to ng-grid in order to get the information I needed.  Here's the link: http://ui-grid.info/.

Comment: Even though you probably found the ui.grid.exporter for your Excel issue, did you figure out how to get the column index in UIGrid?

Comment: @J-Dizzle Yes I did, when/where do you need it?  I can give you an example if you need one.